# How to escape an '&' in the password of a connection string

Tags: c#, web-config, connection-string

So I have a connection string in Visual Studio C#:-

my password is - 'abcs#123ef&wejfl23'

The '&' is throwing the application off...how can I escape this character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You'll need to use escape sequences like you would for any XML document, which is all the .config files are."

```
Ampersand = & = &amp;
Greater Than = > = &gt;
Less Than = < = &lt;
Apostrophe = ' = &apos;
Quote = " = &quot;"
```